# How does merging two pandas dataframes worked using the assignment operation?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

The phenomenon that I am not able to understand is how pandas is able to join two dataframes using the equal operation as in the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(1, 5), "B": np.arange(11, 15)})
df1.index = (np.arange(1, 5) + 1).tolist()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.arange(1, 7), "C": np.arange(21, 27)})
display(df1)
display(df2)
```

[image]

```
df1[["C"]] = df2[["C"]]
display(df1)
```

[image]

I cannot understand how merging happened in this case.

I would appreciate it if someone can guide me toward the original documentation and provide some further explanation for this behavior.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `df1[["C"]] = df2[["C"]]` aligns by index, and re-assigns

Comment: Can you please share the link to the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic feature of pandas, *automatic index alignment*. This is indeed one of the *core features* which distinguishes it from just `numpy` (on top of which it is built). Briefly, at index `2` of `df1`, the new column will get the value `23` (from index `2` in `df2['C']`). At index `3`, the new column will get the value `24` from index `3` in `df['C']`, etc etc –

So, one way you can think of this is that there is no need to do *manual* index alignment, i.e.:

```
df1['C'] = df2.loc[df1.index, 'C']
```

Because

```
df1['C'] = df2['C']
```

does that alignment automatically for you (we could envision an API where this wasn't the case, and the above, for example, throws an error because `df2` is bigger than `df1` so it would be ambiguous what you want to do *without automatic alignment*)

See the [introductory tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html):

> Fundamentally, data alignment is intrinsic. The link between labels and data will not be broken unless done so explicitly by you.

Some more useful parts of the tutorial:

- [vectorized operations and label alignment with series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html#vectorized-operations-and-label-alignment-with-series)

Comment: Col `B` is part of `df1`; and Col `C` is in `df2`; what do you mean by replace?

Comment: @I.A sorry, you are right. Let me rephrase that.

Comment: @I.A I've elaborated some more, let me know if this makes more sense